# How to check the size of PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, size, pfobject

Parse has a limit of 128KB per PFObject. I'm create a PFObject with an array of geo locations (doubles) which I suspect after a while will overflow this 128KB limit. How can I detect the size? Such as splitting the array across multiple PFObjects or as a PFFile.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the size, find the size of your object with an empty array (retrieve and perform size check) and the size with one entry. The empty version will give you the base size then subtract from 128KB and divide by the cost per entry to get the max number of entries.

Do a test to make sure this stores correctly just before you hit the max limit (and fails above it).

It's dangerous to have no limit but I would figure out how large an array you can store within the limit and check against that when adding. If over the limit then you will need to use another object. If the objects have a field in column then your query will return both (or more) objects. Concat their arrays to get all values and only write new data to the object with the array length under the limit.

You could also store each coordinate pair as it's own row and ignore the 128KB limit.